# What determines the max CP and which methods are there to predict them?

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday I started leveling my first pokemon what worked quite different as I expected.

I caught a Raticate and when I made power it up, I noticed it hit a CP cap when the bar was full. I challanged a arena with it (If this is related for the next part) and my whole time died.
Today I noted the same Raticate's CP value remained the same to yesterday, but the cap raised, what led me to my question:

What determines the CP cap, and what may effect this cap(up to whcih final cap)?

And how I can determine early what the cap for a pokemon will in its final stage be so I don't have to waste stardust on them.

Also are there cases where evolving makes the pokemon worse? I had a rattata with XL in size and weight which came to a relative high CP and HP value. So I thought "Ok, this is gonna be extrem if you evolve it!". I evolved it and both stats turned into XS and while still beeing at CPcap, the Raticate had almost the same stats as rattata. So all this is pretty confusing to me, and I don't dare to raise addtional mosnters in fear of wasting resources, but staying low to jsut don't make errors is mindering the fun and therfor I'm lookign here for help.
And how can I de

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Î'll post on meta about it. I'm agreeing that the answers there WOULD also answer this question. If they were trustworhty. But as they are all more or less dubious, and it comes out that NONE of them is actually right, it would be a quite different question, which has as sideffect answers to this question (what admitted is a reason for a dupe) but which are wrong.

Comment: If the answers are not satisfactory, offer a bounty instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: the point is this is a diferent question. just because answers to the other question also might answer this one, what is in generel a valid reason for closing as dupe, doesn't neccesarily mean it is best to place there a bounty if it is not my question. Just wait for the results of my meta post, whats wrong with that?

Comment: I don't see any difference in the questions.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: The linked post asks for the relation between trainer level and max CP. While the answers also get into other factors the OP didn't ask for, but which I'm interested in, that woudl usually be a reason for beeing a dupe, that I agreed with so far. but here it is the case that all of thoose answers are argued about by impressions. they had, which partially contradict with each other or with what I expierienced so far.

Comment: But as they are arguing about additional matter, not asked for by the OP, I'm not sure it is the right choice to place THERE a bounty on getting canon info for something OP didn't even ask. And thats what I want to ask on emta about.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Feel free to bring in your argument if you'd like: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11820/88641